# Vue - change default input text value dynamically

Tags: vue.js

I have a simple Vue form component, it has some text inputs:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="amount">
```

This text input has the following default value:

```
mounted() {
    this.$store.commit('refreshBalance')
  },

  data() {
      return {
        amount: this.$store.getters.baseBalance,
      };
  },
```

The problem with my code is that the value of `amount` is always the same, it doesn't change if i change the value of that Vuex store.

So, for example, if when i open the page `this.$store.getters.baseBalance` is equal to 10 and i change it to 20, the default value of that input field will always be 10. Is there any way i can make it reactive? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where and how do you change the value of the `baseBalance`? Could you post that part of your code?

Comment: Yes, i added it. Basically when the component is loaded, i refresh that value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to a computed property, and use the `get` and `set` methods. You’d also need to create an action in your store to update the baseBalance, which in the code below I’ve named `SET_BALANCE`.

When you update the input, the `set` method runs, which commits the value of `amount` to the store via. `SET_BALANCE`.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="amount">

...

computed: {
  amount: {
    set(amount) {
      this.$store.commit('SET_BALANCE', { amount })
    },
    get() {
      return this.$store.getters.baseBalance
    }
  }
}
```